# iOS + How to catch unhandled exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception

We are writing static library. We have done exception handling for the exposed APIs. But still there are few un-handled Exceptions (or OS Exceptions). Can you please let me know how to catch these unhandled Exceptions.
Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Well, you could always rely on the **[Catch'em All Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2349399#2349399)**

For this kind of problem, I always use following code:

```
@try {
    // do something
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    // error happened! do something about the error state
}
@finally {
    // do something to keep the program still running properly
}
```

Comment: Yes with the try/catch block, we can catch any exception happened in that function or catch exceptions thrown from functions which are getting called from this API.

Comment: With this statement **every** exception will be caught.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`, you probably should add it to AppDelegate

you can finde example on this page: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/tag/nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler/

Answer (score 3):

Simple -

```
       @try
        {
             //your code
        }
        @catch (NSException *theException) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Exception: %@", theException);
        }
```

Happy coding ...

Comment: Is there any way to capture low-level exceptions like system exception/ out of memory exception / hardware exception ?