# Unable to set a context in a private queue as child of another context in main queue

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext

As far as I understood, it is possible to create an `NSManagedObjectContext` in a private queue and set its parent context to be another `NSManagedObjectContext` that belongs to main thread... isn't it?

I'm trying to do this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *privateContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
[privateContext setParentContext:mainContext];
```

But I get a `SIGABRT` error at `[privateContext setParentContext:mainContext]` when I run this code.

The `mainContext` I retrieve from `AppDelegate` is initialized in main thread, and this code snippet is also called in main thread. What could I doing wrong or missing?

Thanks

**EDIT:** If I instead do this (in `AppDelegate`):

```
NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
mainContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator;
NSManagedObjectContext *privateContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

privateContext.parentContext = mainContext;
```

I get no error... why could this be happening? What does the default context provided in `AppDelegate` have that it doesn't work as parent context?

**EDIT 2:** The context in `AppDelegate` I'm trying to set as parent context is initialized by using the methods that are provided by default in `AppDelegate`:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
   // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.)
   if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
       return _managedObjectContext;
   }

   NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
   if (!coordinator) {
       return nil;
   }
   _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
   [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
   return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to detect what does throw the exception in your case - too less info.

At a first glance everything seems fine, but - please, mind setting up your parent/child contexts in following order:

1. Create root context.
2. Set its `persistentStoreCoordinator`
3. Create child context
4. Set its `parentContext` to root context
5. Continue setting up parent/child hierarchy with 3-4

In your case exception may arise due to:

1. `mainContext` is `nil`
2. `mainContext`'s `persistentStoreCoordinator` is `nil`

Anyway, the fastest solution will be log exception fired by a CoreData. You may use [NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7646091/2392973)

**EDIT 1:**

To ne consistent try to use `NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];` in your initialization method in `AppDelegate`  instead of `alloc/init` but it's most likely not the fix of the problem. Again, read the exception message in the console - this will give an exact idea what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my question to provide the initialization method of the `mainContext`, that is the one that I was provided in `AppDelegate`, I made no changes. `mainContext` is already initialized when I try to set it as parent context, could it be because the initialization method needs any change?

Comment: @AppsDev i've edited my answer a bit - again, read the error message plz

Comment: You were right, this is the exception message I get: `Parent NSManagedObjectContext must use either NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType or NSMainQueueConcurrencyType.`. Thanks